# How do I get a .csv file, text formatted date to not to be converted to the date format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, javascript, cvs

When I import a .csv or a .txt file into Excel the text formatted date, i.e. "Nov-24" (2021) (double quotes are in the file, 2021 is not) is converted to the date format and the current year is added i.e. 11/24/2022 and is displayed as 24-Nov. Try sorting by date after it does that!

It appears the double quotes on the text date field is being ignored in Excel. The Text qualifier: field is set to ". How to get my text date imported as text? What needs to be in the .csv file, other than the double quotes, so Excel will know to keep the text date in the text format?

The CSV file is created using JavaScript.

Comment: Sorting by date should be easier now if it understands the date, unless of course this was 24 nov 2021.

Comment: It is "24 Nov" 2021

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/26/excel-convert-text-date/ Is this article helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Use the file processing dialogue rather than simply opening the .csv/.txt file in Excel.

The dialog appears via Data Menu > Get & Transfrom Data group > Get Data button > From File option > From Text/CSV sub-option after a file is selected using the standard file picker. The file processing dialogue should allow fields to be imported as as-is. This prevents the import routine from applying its "intelligence" (decision rules) and "deciding" how the content in the file gets converted to values in the worksheet.

The following test file

[image: Simple text file]

was was selected for import and, after selecting the file, the file processing dialog appeared as

[image: File processing dialog]

Note that the dialog was effectively indicating that "Nov-24" in the .txt file would be imported as the date 01/11/2024 (or 11/01/2024 under the mm/dd/yyyy convention).

However, by selecting "Do not detect data types", in the control labelled "Data Type Detection" this was prevented.

The imported data looks like

[image: Imported file in worksheet]

As can be observed from the formula in cell `E2`, the value `Nov-24` showing in cell `A2` is not a number (and therefore not a date), just a text string (though it loses the double quotes present in the .txt file).

In fact, all the values imported were treated as text strings when "Do not detect data types" was selected, including the numbers 12, 87.2, 25 and 42.1.

The above was undertaken using Office 365. Earlier versions of Excel have quite different versions of the file import dialog and, if memory serves, allow more control at the column level (so allowing only some columns to be imported as text strings).